# Reading from flushed vs unflushed buffers

Tags: python, c, shell, ipc

I've got a script `parent.py` trying to to read stdout from a subprocess `sub.py` in Python.

The parent `parent.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("sub.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout.read(1)
```

And the subprocess, `sub.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print raw_input( "hello world!" )
```

I would expect running `parent.py` to print the 'h' from "hello world!". Actually, it hangs.  I can only get my expected behaviour by adding `-u` to `sub.py`'s she-bang line.

This confuses me because the `-u` switch makes no difference when `sub.py` is run directly from a shell; the shell is somehow privy to the un-flushed output stream, unlike `parent.py`.

My goal is to run a C program as the subprocess, so I won't be able to control whether or not it flushes stdout. How is it that a shell has better access to a process's stdout than Python running the same thing from `subprocess.Popen`? Am I going to be able to read such a stdout stream from a C program that doesn't flush its buffers?

**EDIT:**

Here is an updated example based on korylprince's comment...

```
## capitalize.sh ##
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ]; do
    read s
    echo $s | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
done

########################################

## parent.py ##
#!/usr/bin/python 
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# cmd = [ 'capitalize.sh' ] # This would work
cmd = [ 'script', '-q', '-f', '-c', 'capitalize.sh', '/dev/null']

p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("some string\n")
p.wait()
```

When running through `script`, I get steady printing of newlines (and if this were a Python,  subprocess, it'd raise an EOFerror).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-u", "sub.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering).

My experience is that yes, you will be able to read from most C programs without any extra effort.

The Python interpreter takes extra steps to buffer its output which is why it needs the `-u` switch to disable output buffering.  Your typical C program won't do this.

I haven't run into any program (C or otherwise) other than the Python interpreter that I expected to work and didn't within a subshell.

Comment: I dealt with this problem before. Not all C programs will work. There is an awesome unix command called script that will make things work for you though. See my question that uses it similarly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131825/main-python-process-is-stopped-using-subprocess-calls-in-socketserver

Comment: It not working with my `c_prog`. If I pipe it's stdout to a file, and then keyboard-interrupt, the file will be empty. But if I let it terminate naturally, the output makes it to the file.. I suspect this is related.

Comment: @korylprince: When I run the subproces through `script` using PIPEs for both std and stdout, the subprocess seems to fail with an EOFError.

Comment: @korylprince: Actually, even if the only pipe is for stdin, subprocess fails when run though `script`

Answer (score 0):

The reason the shell can read output immediately, regardless of "-u" is because the program you're launching from the shell has its output connected to a TTY.  When the stdout is connected to a TTY, it is unbuffered (because it is up to the TTY to buffer).  When you launch the python subprocess from within python, you're connecting stdout to a pipe, which means you're at the mercy of the subprocess to flush its output when it feels like it.

If you're looking to do complicated interactions with a subprocess, look into [this tutorial.](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/tutorials/2-interacting_with_processes.html)