# Force bash executed in a pipe to enable echoing

Tags: python, bash

I'm making a webshell in `python`, so actually, the user will use his favourite shell trough a web server. My idea is to create a `subprocess.Popen` with `bash -i`  and to make two functions `read` and `write` in the webapp that, respectively, read the `stdout` or write in the `stdin` of the `subprocess`.

I start the shell with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["script","-f","-c","bash -i -l"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The writing is Ok, but when I read the standard output I don't read the user typing:

```
        while select.select([p.stdout],[],[],0)[0]!=[] or select.select([p.stderr],[],[],0)[0]!=[]:
            if(select.select([p.stdout],[],[],0)[0]!=[]): data+=p.stdout.read(1)
            if(select.select([p.stderr],[],[],0)[0]!=[]): data+=p.stderr.read(1)
```

I could force the echoing adding the user input to the output but that's not very elegant because, if the user uses some program that prevent echoing (like a password input), the user input would always be shown in the web page.

So, there is a way, like an option in the `bash` parameters, to force it adding the input to the output?

---

PS: If you wonder why I'm using `script` to run `bash` is because running `bash` alone will cause `python` to stop itself with

```
[1]+  Stopped                 python RPCServer.py
```

Altough I've not figured out WHY it happens, i've found how to prevent it from this question: [Main Python Process is stopped using subprocess calls in SocketServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131825/main-python-process-is-stopped-using-subprocess-calls-in-socketserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, there is a way, like an option in the `bash` parameters, to force it adding the input to the output?

Yes: you can use the `-v` command-line option ("Print shell input lines as they are read.").

Comment: I'd prefer a character wise echoing, but it's something!